# how to send parameter concatenated with string using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have to post a raw body data to server for eg: `param={username=@"",password=@""}` .I know how to send parameter but how to send `param={}`? M trying below code but fails.

```
 NSDictionary *params =@{@"username":self.UsernameTF.text, @"password":self.PswdTF.text};
[manager POST:@"http://clients.view9.com.au/golfapp/cidev/admin-panel/service/registerNewUser" parameters:[NSString stringWithFormat@"param=%@",params]
```

edit:
Below code give me what i want to post to server but how to remove curly starting braces

```
  NSMutableDictionary *paramArray=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


[paramArray setObject:self.UsernameTF.text forKey:@"username"];
[paramArray setObject:self.PswdTF.text forKey:@"password"];


NSDictionary *params =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:paramArray,@"params", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *url = @"http://clients.view9.com.au/golfapp/cidev/admin-panel/service/registerNewUser";

NSDictionary *params = @{@"param":[NSString stringWithFormat:"username=%@,password=%@",self.UsernameTF.tex, self.PswdTF.text]};

[manager POST:url parameters:params];
```

Hey, try this instead. 
Tell me if it doesn't work!

Comment: I want to post this to server  :                                                              params={"useremail":"fg@view9.com.np", "firstname":"q","lastname":"sg","username":"hgd", "password":"ru", "user_type_id":"3", "state":"1", "fb_id":"","image":""  }

Comment: With ur code m getting this:    {
    params = "useremail=poo@gmail.com,firstname=Ayush,lastname=Gupta,username=poo,password=poo,user_type_id=3,state=1,fb_id=,image=";
}
2015-04-19 11:34:53.596 App[3792:65189] success {
    code = 2;
    message = "Problem supply all required fields";

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager POST:url parameters:[NSString stringWithFormat@"param=%@",params]];
```

Comment: Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7a76b3c0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.} responseobj=Disallowed Key Characters.

Comment: oh yeah, you need to pass in NSDictionary. Well you need to go into `AFNetworking` code and tweak in there.

Comment: look at my edit answer: i have used afnetworking but still not getting it

Comment: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
            manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
            manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
                            manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

Comment: manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
            
    NSMutableDictionary *paramArray=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];  [paramArray setObject:self.UsernameTF.text forKey:@"username"];
    [paramArray setObject:self.PswdTF.text forKey:@"password"];

Comment: yeah!!after all that above edited code of mine.Plzz see the json that i have to post under pedros comment.But after trying all that i am getting below json -----> {
    params =     {
        "fb_id" = "";
        firstname = ssd;
        image = "";
        lastname = ssd;
        password = sds;
        state = 1;
        "user_type_id" = 3;
        useremail = dsds;
        username = dsd;
    };
}

Comment: And error block code m getting------>>>> Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x796d5080 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.} responseobj=<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/service.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 65</p>

Answer (score 0):

The catch in this situation is that you are not sending JSON to the server, you are sending url form enconding that happens to have a JSON String at the right side of the equal.

If you have control over the server I will recommend you to go for a full JSON approach and make the server accept either

`{"param":{"username":"yourusername","password":"yourpassword"}}`

or

`{"username":"yourusername","password":"yourpassword"}`

But if that is not possible you will need to:

- Change the request serializer from `AFJSONRequestSerializer` to
  `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`.
- Transform your dictionary to a JSONString
- Set a new dictionary {@"param":YourJSONString}

If you look at the content of YourJSONString should look like this:

`@"{\"username\":\"yourusername\",\"password\":\"yourpassword\"}"`

And when finally parsed into the body of the request:

`param={"username":"yourusername","password":"yourpassword"}`

Comment: ur code tried---> NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"useremail\":\"%@\",\"firstname\"=\"%@\",\"lastname\"=\"%@\",\"username\"=\"%@\",\"password\"=\"%@\",\"user_type_id\"=\"%@\",\"state\"=\"%@\",\"fb_id\"=\"%@\",\"image\"=\"%@\"}",self.emailTF.text,@"Ay",@"Gg",self.UsernameTF.text,self.PswdTF.text,@"3",@"1",@"",@""];
    NSDictionary *param=@{@"params":str};
    NSLog(@"paramDict=%@",param);

Comment: it enter the success block but response stringis:{code:2,msg:"problem supply all reqd filed"}.api is unable to detect parse json m sending..

Comment: thnx mate all done..ur awsum :) and xtremely sori cant vote up as i need 15 reputation

Comment: Glad this help you, if this solve your problem make it the accepted answer. Also you can vote it up later if you feel like it ;). Cheers